# How do you access Telerik RadEditor control (embedded in Content page) in master page's code behind?

Tags: c#, .net, telerik

if (ContentPlaceHolders.Contains(Telerik.RadEditor))
        {
            label1.Text = ("lkjjljlj!");
        }

the above apparently didnt work

[edit] tried the following..

```
if(ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Equals(Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor))
{
            label1.Text = ("lkjjljlj!");
        }
```

its giving the error "'Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context"

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of methods to do what you want:

//loop
foreach (Control control in MyContentPlaceHolder.Controls)
{
  if(typeof(control).Equals(Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor)
  {
    //set the text of the label
  }
}

//reference the editor directly by its id, if applicable
MyContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("RadEditorIDHere")